# Using .Find in Word Causes Infinite Loop

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I created a Loop to find each iteration of some HTML code and return the e-mail data as a string.  What we are looking for is:

```
'Jibberish HTML Code
<p><b><font color="#000066" size="3" face="Arial">Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:</font></b></p>
<font color="#000000" size="2" face="Tahoma"><p><a href="mailto:last.first@location.company.com">last.first@location.company.com</a><br>
'Jibberish HTML Code
<p><b><font color="#000066" size="3" face="Arial">Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:</font></b></p>
<font color="#000000" size="2" face="Tahoma"><p><a href="mailto:last.first@location.company.com">last.first@location.company.com</a><br>
'Jibberish HTML Code
<p><b><font color="#000066" size="3" face="Arial">Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:</font></b></p>
<font color="#000000" size="2" face="Tahoma"><p><a href="mailto:last.first@location.company.com">last.first@location.company.com</a><br>
```

This code will find the FIRST iteration and as of right now the Loop creates an infite loop on the first found value (doesn't move to next found value:

```
Sub RevisedFindIt()
' Purpose: display the text between (but not including)
' the words "Title" and "Address" if they both appear.
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim strTheText As String

    Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
    With rng1.Find
        .Execute FindText:="<font color=" & Chr(34) & "#000000" & Chr(34) & " size=" & Chr(34) & "2" & Chr(34) & " face=" & Chr(34) & "Tahoma" & Chr(34) & "><p><a href=" & Chr(34) & "mailto:", Forward:=True

    Do While .Found
        Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
        If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:=Chr(34) & ">") Then
            strTheText = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
            'Debug.Print strTheText
            CreateObject("Excel.Application").Run "'TestExport.xlsm'!RunIt", strTheText
        End If
    Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

The data is being passed to an Excel Sub:

```
Public Sub RunIt(strTheText As String)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Debug.Print strTheText & "Test"
    LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = strTheText
End Sub
```

How do I get the search to skip to the next iteration in Word VBA?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  How should it behave?  When should it "skip to the next iteration"?  And what is the "next iteration" since `rng1.Found` only executes once?

Comment: @roryap See the first block of "code" which is more the text in the document.  The find should jump to each line that matches and return the e-mail address.  It currently works for the FIRST e-mail address in the document but doesn't move forward.  I am unsure how to change `rng1` to exclude already found and continue search remainder of document.

Comment: Hey @Chrismas007: Why don't you do a regex to get the e-mails?

Comment: @JLILIAman Primarily because I've never used them before and this method should work with a small tweak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing the `rng1` mid loop and refinding the data:

```
Sub RevisedFindIt()
' Purpose: display the text between (but not including) two strings
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim strTheText As String

    Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
        Do
            With rng1.Find
                .Execute FindText:="<font color=" & Chr(34) & "#000000" & Chr(34) & " size=" & Chr(34) & "2" & Chr(34) & " face=" & Chr(34) & "Tahoma" & Chr(34) & "><p><a href=" & Chr(34) & "mailto:"
                If .Found Then
                    Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
                    If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:=Chr(34) & ">") Then
                        strTheText = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
                        'Debug.Print strTheText
                        CreateObject("Excel.Application").Run "'TestExport.xlsm'!RunIt", strTheText
                    End If
                    Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng2.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End With
        Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: ups! I was few seconds late with my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, all you need is simple:

```
.execute
```

before your only

```
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks to be because the value of `rng1.Found` never changes once you're inside the `Do While .Found` loop.  The `.Found` in `Do While .Found` refers to `rng1.Found` because of the `With rng1.Find` statement that contains it.

Comment: That doesn't really give a solution, just points out the problem.

Comment: @Chrismas007 -- I'm not trying to solve the problem.  The question is about why it's happening.  There's a multitude of possible ways to solve the problem.

Comment: The question is "How do I get the search to skip to the next iteration in Word VBA?"

Comment: @Chrismas007 -- Okay, bear with me, I'll propose a solution.

Comment: @Chrismas007 -- See my comments under your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub M_snb()
  sn = Split(Replace(Join(Filter(Split(LCase(ActiveDocument.Content), Chr(34)), "mailto:"), "|"), "mailto:", ""), "|")

  With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    .workbooks.Add().sheets(1).Cells(1).Resize(UBound(sn) + 1) = .Application.transpose(sn)
    .Visible = True
  End With
End Sub
```